# Convert the hexadecimal representation of a binary double-precision number back into a double in Ruby

Tags: ruby, double, numerical-methods

How can I convert a double-precision hexadecimal back into a double?

For example, given the string `'4045000000000000'`, how do I get back to the double `42.0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pack the hexadecimal into bytes and unpack them as a double:

```
['4045000000000000'].pack("H*").unpack("G").first # => 42.0
```

Comment: I thought unpack was in there somewhere. Thanks for your help.